# ClickOnce application skips asking for an update (or fail launch if skip is selected)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, clickonce, .net-3.5, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I updated my ClickOnce application and then when the user runs they are asked if they want to install the new version.

I am working in a highly controlled environment. When an update is available it has to be installed (backwards compatibility with the database is not ensured with old versions).

Another option is to fail the run if skip is pressed (that works fine too).

I need some way to stop them from running an old version of the application.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This article answers your question.  I'm pointing you to the article instead of just posting an answer because everything in the article is worth knowing.

http://www.sayedhashimi.com/CategoryView,category,ClickOnce.aspx

The following is the relevant excerpt from the article:

> Forcing ClickOnce Updates
>
> One of the big selling points of
>   ClickOnce is automatic updates. One of
>   the common questions I get with regard
>   to updates is "How can I force an
>   update on the user?"
>
> There are three things to know with
>   respect to forcing updates on users:
>
> 1) If your application is an online
>   application, your users will always
>   run the latest version; online
>   applications get downloaded everytime
>   the application is accessed. Thus,
>   with online applications, you get
>   forced-updates by default.
>
> 2) If your application is an installed
>   application, you can force updates by
>   using the MinimumRequiredVersion
>   attribute. If you publish your
>   application using Visual Studio, you
>   can set this property from the Updates
>   Dialog.
>
> 3) The last thing to note is that if
>   your application is an installed
>   application (and you have not set the
>   MinimumRequiredVersion attribute)
>   ClickOnce will prompt the user with an
>   "Update Available" dialog ONLY if the
>   user launches the application from the
>   Start Menu shortcut. That is, if an
>   application is an installed
>   application and the user launches the
>   application from a URL, ClickOnce
>   forces the update.

---

I also found another good article:

*[ClickOnce: Bringing Ease and Reliability to Smart Client Deployment](http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0601041&page=3)*

Comment: Thanks for the answers, very helpful! :)
Just a note too that the sayedhashimi.com link is broken.

Comment: I've documented a process for automatically updating the MinimumRequiredVersion attribute when using method 2 at http://geekswithblogs.net/deadlydog/archive/2012/08/15/force-clickonce-applications-to-automatically-update-without-prompting-user.aspx

Comment: I've now created a NuGet package that automatically handles all of the setup/installation that the article in my comment above talks about. The NuGet package is at https://nuget.org/packages/AutoUpdateProjectsMinimumRequiredClickOnceVersion, and this blog post explains it a little more (https://deadlydog.wordpress.com/2013/03/08/force-your-clickonce-app-to-update-without-prompting-user-now-on-nuget/).

Comment: Here is a cached contents of the first link on a different site - http://sedodream.com/CategoryView,category,ClickOnce.aspx

Comment: The first link seems to be broken (not in DNS?).

Comment: "Starting in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8, you can use the Publish tool to publish .NET Core 3.1, .NET 5, or newer, Windows Desktop applications (...)" However, the .Net version of ClickOnce is massively neutered. There is only user-prompted update (skip once, never prompt again), or forced update with the `MinimumRequiredVersion` property specifying a version. The user will not get an update prompt until a version newer than the skipped one is available, if `MinimumRequiredVersion` is &lte; than the skipped version.

Answer (score 6):

This neatly worked for me. Add the following to the project file:

```
<UpdateRequired>true</UpdateRequired>
<MinimumRequiredVersion>$(ApplicationVersion)</MinimumRequiredVersion>
```

Note that `ApplicationVersion` cannot have a value like `1.0.0.*` in the project file and it should be incremented at build time for auto-update to work.

If using **TeamCity**, to increment the version number go to **Build Configuration** page for your project and set the following **System Property**:

```
system.ApplicationVersion = %build.number%
```

You can also get **MSBuild** to increment version by time with something like this:

```
<UpdateRequired>true</UpdateRequired>
<BuildNumber>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString(yyyyMMdd))</BuildNumber>
<RevisionNumber>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString(mmss))</RevisionNumber>
<ApplicationVersion>1.0.$(BuildNumber).$(RevisionNumber)</ApplicationVersion>
<MinimumRequiredVersion>$(ApplicationVersion)</MinimumRequiredVersion>
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1638096/602585), simply install the [AutoUpdateProjectsMinimumRequiredClickOnceVersion nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoUpdateProjectsMinimumRequiredClickOnceVersion) in your project. Once you have your project set to check for updates and to use a minimum required version, this will handle making sure the minimum required version always matches your current version (i.e. user's will always be forced to update to the latest version).

Answer (score 1):

It worked me by unchecking *The application should check for updates*, and the application started updating without prompting the user after two versions.

[image]

Comment: This will only work if you handle Updates in code using the Clickonce API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404263.aspx

Comment: yes my code is handling updates in Program.cs i reload the code if assembly has a newer version

Answer (score 0):

To force an update on the clients you must set the minimum version field equals to the current version you are deploying, this will force the update whiout "skip" option.