# Host Application Online, Only Download Newer Version

Tags: .net, web, deployment, clickonce

Excuse me if this is not technically a programming question but I've spent the last 2 weeks on this to no avail.

I want to host my application (vb.net, winform) on a web server, embed the application URL in a config opened by a program used by my client daily. What I want is:

First time the program opens, download and install my application.
Every time the program opens after that, my URL is opened and if the application on the server is of a newer version then the one installed on the client's device, install it. If not do nothing.

I want this to be done without opening webpages to the user and asking him to keep clicking on "Next" and so on. It would be annoying if everyday he has to see a webpage telling him he has the latest version of the application installed.

I tried ClickOnce Deployment but couldn't get it to do what I want. It works the other way around, every time the application is opened manually it checks for updates on the server.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: [Automatically install updates with ClickOnce deployment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843369/automatically-install-updates-with-clickonce-deployment)?

Comment: Thanks CodeCaster but this is not what I was really looking for. Using ClickOnce, the user opens the application from his machine after it is installed the first time and then the app checks for updates.
I want it so that every time the link to the ".application" manifest file is clicked, if a new version exists on the server then download and ask to install, if not then do nothing and do not show anything to the user when checking the versions

Comment: I'm not sure that's any different. Read the link, try it.